# The unofficial definition of Group.

Tags: group-theory

As in the Visual Group Theory Book the unofficial definition of a group says that :

A group is a collection of actions satisfying the rules:
1. there is a predefined list of actions that never change.
2. Every actions is reversible.
3. Every actions is deterministic.
4. Any sequence of consecutive actions is also an action.

Each of the above rules relate to which corresponding rules in official definition of group?

Also in particular i'm in fix over the 3rd rule above.

Comment: What is meant, in this context, by "deterministic"?

Comment: What is the official definition, and which pairing do you, yourself, think is appropriate?

Comment: @Fragle The book consider an action is deterministic ,whose outcomes can be determined in advance ,free from influences that are random or uncertain,is deterministic.e.g. The turning of face of cube has predictable outcome.

Comment: @Fargle Most likely that if action $a$ equals action $b$, then the result of action $a$ equals the result of action $b$. i.e., equal inputs imply equal outputs.

Comment: @David H Please explain a bit more as I am confused by your definition of what deterministic is and the book's definition as added above in my comment to Fragle.

Answer (score 2):

1 corresponds to group being a set. Not one of the traditional "fundamental properties" of a group, but still important to the group definition.

2 corresponds to the axioms of inverse and identity. For an action to be reversible, it has to have an "inverse action" which undoes it, and there has to be a notion of undoing an action--namely, the composition of an action with its inverse should be the null action, or the identity.

4 corresponds to closure.

3 just seems to refer to the actions being well-defined.

In particular, I see no analogue to associativity.

Comment: Closure doesn't imply associativity: the 4th statement says a composition of actions is still an action but doesn't say anything about the order and how it affect the resulting action

Comment: I think at this level of non-rigor associativity is just a given. Non-associativity is fairly bizarre, and anyone at this level would just implicitly assume it holds without even being aware of the concept.

Comment: 3 could also be regarded as saying that each individual action is a function.